# Uniform Boundedness Principle for $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1\leq p<\infty$, and $q$ the conjugate of $p$ (i.e., $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$). Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^p(E)$ such that for each $g\in L^q(E)$, the sequence $\{\int_Eg\cdot f_n\}$ is bounded. Show that $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p(E)$.

This problem is from Royden's real analysis book (Chapter 8, Ex 26). It is required that the proof cannot directly make use of the Uniform Boundedness Principle.

Comment: There is a way, which I think is actually pointed out in Royden, to take a function $f \in L^p$ and find a function $g \in L^q$ with $\| g \|_{L^q}=1$ such that $\int fg = \| f \|_{L^p}$ (i.e. to make Holder's inequality tight). Do you see how such a construction would solve your problem?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @ Ian Yes, I know this construction. I think you mean the conjugate function of $f$, right? However, for each $f_n$, we need a specific $g_n=f_n^*$. But I think we need to find a single $g$ which satisfies the condition.

Comment: @ Alp Uzman Yes, this is a homework question.

Comment: @user147687 You have that for each $g \in L^q$, the sequence $\int_E g f_n$ is bounded. So you can take $g$ to be $f_1^*,f_2^*,\dots$ and in each case you'll have a bounded sequence. Can you now do some kind of diagonalization or similar to conclude that the sequence $\int_E f_n^* f_n$ must be bounded? (Note that this is exactly the conclusion you require...)

Comment: @Ian What do you mean by diagonalization?

Comment: @user147687 If you're still just as confused at Ian's suggestion as I am at this moment, I believe there is an alternative. If you look at the proof of theorem 7 in 8.2, Royden constructs a function $g$ for which $\{\int_E f_n g \}$ is unbounded. So, assume that $||f_n|| = n \cdot 3^n$ wlog, and I believe you can go go through the same construction to arrive at a contradiction.